# Why is the following C++ code giving an error in release mode but works fine in debug mode?

Tags: io, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to read 2 integers from a file and write their sum to another file. On running the following code in release mode (Visual Studio 2017 Community)

```
    // Kickstart.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string inpath = "E:\\Pratik\\Kickstart\\Inputs\\Sum.txt";
    string outpath = "E:\\Pratik\\Kickstart\\Outputs\\Sum.txt";
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    fin.open(inpath);
    fout.open(outpath);
    if (!fin)
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open input file";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!fout)
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open output file";
        exit(1);
    }
    int sum = 0;
    int a, b;
    fin >> a >> b;
    cout << "a: " << a << "b: " << b << endl; //Line in question
    fout << a + b;
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error on running it in Release mode (x64, Local Windows Debugger)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Kickstart, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Kickstart.cpp
1>Generating code
1>LINK : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 258)
1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>  link!InvokeCompilerPass()+0x1f1b9
1>  link!InvokeCompilerPass()+0x1f1b9
1>  link!InvokeCompilerPass()+0x1ebd3
1>  link!DllGetC2Telemetry()+0x10769b
1>
1>LINK : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 258)
1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>  link!InvokeCompilerPass()+0x1f1b9
1>  link!InvokeCompilerPass()+0x1ebd3
1>  link!DllGetC2Telemetry()+0x10769b
1>
1>
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IMAGE::BuildImage
1>
1>  Version 14.12.25831.0
1>
1>  ExceptionCode            = C0000005
1>  ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
1>  ExceptionAddress         = 063636E6 (05F30000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x64\c2.dll"
1>  NumberParameters         = 00000002
1>  ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
1>  ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 0FA6D358
1>
1>CONTEXT:
1>  Eax    = 0FA6D358  Esp    = 008FE9E8
1>  Ebx    = 05A500EC  Ebp    = 008FEA18
1>  Ecx    = 00000005  Esi    = 0FA6D358
1>  Edx    = 08C8C02C  Edi    = 008FE9F8
1>  Eip    = 063636E6  EFlags = 00010202
1>  SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
1>  SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
1>  SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
1>  Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
1>  Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
1>  Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
1>Done building project "Kickstart.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

On tinkering with the code, I discovered that commenting out the cout line (has a "Line in question" comment) makes the code run properly. My initial suspicion was that since the 2 variables are written to stdout stream, they cannot be written to ofstream. However, when I comment out the "fout"<<"a"<<"b" line (next to "Line in question"), I get the same error. This means the variables just refuse to be loaded in stdout stream (Am I right?). I am not able to figure out why is this happening. A google search for "writing variables to multiple streams in C++" was not helpful either.

Now, when I select Debug mode in Visual Studio and apply a breakpoint (at string inpath declaration and assignment) and step through the code (no code is commented. The code given above is stepped through as it is), it runs successfully. It prints the values of a and b on stdout (console screen) and the sum is also written in the output file.

So there are 2 things happening here:
1 - In Release mode, the variables can be written only to ofstream but not on console screen.

2 - In Debug mode, the code behaves exactly the way I want.

Note - The content in my input file is 2 numbers (5 and 9) separated by a space. I am running Visual Studio 2017 community on Windows 10

Can someone please explain what exactly is happening here? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug if you ask me..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry for the noob question but can I do something about it?

Comment: Report it. And try to work around, by replacing the offending command by some equivalent.